# How to move <p> a little bit left with css?

Tags: html, css

I have an html file like this.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="final_time">
      <p class="final_time_text">some text here</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is its corresponding css file.

```
.final_time {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  
}
.final_time_text {
  width: 200px;
  left: -20px;
}
```

How can I move `.final_time_text` a little bit left so that it aligns to the center of `.final_time`?

I mean I want something like this.

[image]

I originally thought that setting `left: -20px` can make it shift left a little bit, but I was wrong.

Here's the code in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rf2vnozq/4/

Comment: set position:relative to .final_time_text, it will apply left property

Comment: Changing a bit the structure of the html is very easy. Can you change the structure or does it have to be like this?

Comment: @Coolis The structure doesn't have to be like this. Do you have a better idea for the structure?

Comment: I was going to to suggest flex box as well but @AliSattarzadeh beat me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add relative position to the text css

```css
.final_time {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  
}
.final_time_text {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="final_time">
      <p class="final_time_text">some text here</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm a beginner with html and css.

Answer (score 2):

I think setting  position:relative to .final_time_text will do what you want
but it would be better to centerlize it using flex box

like this :

```css
.final_time {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
 /*increase distance of green circle and text*/
  margin-bottom:10px;

}
.final_time_text {
  width: 200px;
  text-align:center;
}

.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="final_time">
     
    </div>
     <p class="final_time_text">some text here</p>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks like a more advanced technique.

Comment: How can I adjust the distance between the green circle and the text while using flex box? I'd like to make it a little bit shorter.

Comment: there are lots of ways to do that, you can use margin-bottom 
let me update my answer